# Dynamic div id for Multilevel accordion in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to AngularJS.
I have a 2- level accordion in my application.

```
 <div class="box-group" id="accordion" ng-repeat="item in tourList">
    <div class="panel box box-primary">
    <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
    {{item.Name}}
    </a>
    </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
                            <div class="box-body">
                                <div class="box-group" id="accordion1" ng-repeat="itinerary in item.Itineraries">
                                    <!-- we are adding the .panel class so bootstrap.js collapse plugin detects it -->
                                    <div class="panel box box-primary">
                                        <div class="box-header with-border">
                                            <h4 class="box-title">
                                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseItin" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">
                                                    {{itinerary.Name}}
                                                </a>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
```

I want to create dynamic id for the accordion div and also assign it to the parent accordion.

Any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the dynamic id by making use of the implicit $index property exposed by the ngRepeat directive. In order to deal with nested ngRepeat's you can also alias the $index property via the ngInit directive. This makes it clear which $index property is being referenced where.

Given ...

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('ctrl',
  function($scope) {

    $scope.tourList = [{
      Name: "Tour 1",
      Itineraries: [{
        Name: "tour 1 itin 1",
        Stops: ["A","B"]
      }, {
        Name: "tour 1 itin 2",
        Stops: ["C","D"]
      }]
    }, {
      Name: "Tour 2",
      Itineraries: [{
        Name: "tour 2 itin 1",
        Stops: ["E","F"]
      }, {
        Name: "tour 2 itin 2",
        Stops: ["G","H"]
      }]
    }]
  }
);
```

... the following nested accordions work correctly ...

```
<div class="box-group" id="tourAccordion_{{tourIndex}}" ng-repeat="item in tourList" ng-init="tourIndex=$index">
<div class="panel box box-primary">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <h4 class="box-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#tourAccordion_{{tourIndex}}" href="#collapse_{{tourIndex}}" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">{{item.Name}}</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse_{{tourIndex}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
    <div class="box-body">
      <div class="box-group" id="itineraryAccordion_{{tourIndex}}_{{itineraryIndex}}" ng-repeat="itinerary in item.Itineraries" ng-init="itineraryIndex=$index">
        <!-- we are adding the .panel class so bootstrap.js collapse plugin detects it -->
        <div class="panel box box-primary">
          <div class="box-header with-border">
            <h4 class="box-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#itineraryAccordion_{{tourIndex}}_{{itineraryIndex}}" href="#collapseItin_{{tourIndex}}_{{itineraryIndex}}" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed">{{itinerary.Name}}</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <ul id="collapseItin_{{tourIndex}}_{{itineraryIndex}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <li ng-repeat="stop in itinerary.Stops">{{stop}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/XQUq63

... for both ngRepeats I am using the available $index values (aliased for clarity/readability) to ensure that the IDs are unique.

*NOTE:* It is usual convention that property names should begin with a lower case letter. I have kept your naming convention simply for consistency between question and answer.

Comment: In the code I provided , can you find the div id : collapseOne . This id is referred in <a href> above it. If I create a dynamic ID, how will I mention the same in <a href> tag.? Can you help?

Comment: Example added and plunkr provided

Comment: I've updated my answer and the Plunkr because there was an issue when I added an extra level of data and I needed to use $parent.$index to resolve that.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
In case I need to add one more accordion, how can I frame the id.?
I tried like this , but it didnt work .

#scheduleAccordion_{{$parent.$parent.$index}}_{{$parent.$index}}_{{$index}}

Comment: That should have worked fine. You could try using the ngInit aliasing instead as that really comes into its own the deeper the nesting gets. I presume you did set the corresponding id exactly the same to match the href reference?

Comment: I've added an extra level of nesting to the Plunkr and it works fine. I have made use of ngInit aliasing throughout except at the end (see comment) where I deliberately use $parent.$parent.$index instead and it works fine - alias does not stop $index being available as normal.

Comment: Thanks again..! One more doubt..if you dont mind..which is out of scope of this thread.

Like ng-Init , is there any attribute which helps me to replace {{item.Name}}. I am asking this because, in case if it takes time to page load, then the scope variable is getting displayed as such on the page, which is undesirable.

Comment: Have a read about ngBind and also ngCloak - the first will directly address your issue by stopping it happening altogether and the second helps "mitigate" the problem when ngBind can't be used.

Comment: One more help. I want to implement here one accordion to be open at a time. If I click on the Tour2, Tour1 should automatically collapse. Likewise, ITINERARIES, STOPS .. I understand I have to add a Group in the class, but since the I am constructing only one accordion and rest is in ng-repeat , how will I implement grouping

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the answer to that one. I'd suggest you open a new question. Good luck.